# Eclipse Enabling Annotation Processing leads to Errors

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, gradle

I have Eclipse Luna and a standard GWT web application project. I tried to enable annotation processing tho make [Dagger2](https://github.com/google/dagger) working. Here are my project specific configurations:

[image]

[image]

After I hit apply Eclipse shows me the following error:

[image]

**How do I solve this error?**

**Edit:** I created a demo project to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/confile/GWT-Dagger2-Demo

I looked at the pom.xml of dagger2 compiler and added further dependencies but still no progress. Here is what I did:

[image]

Edit: I tried to use the dagger2 compiler jar with dependencies from [here](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/2.0-SNAPSHOT/):

When I do GWT compile I get the following errors:

```
Compiling module test.GWTT
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'test.client.test2.Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Eclipse/Eclipse-4.4/GWTT/.apt_generated/test/client/test2/Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector.java'
         [ERROR] Line 9: No source code is available for type javax.inject.Provider<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   Tracing compile failure path for type 'test.client.test2.MyWidgetClientModule$$ProvideSomeServiceFactory'
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/Users/mg/Documents/Eclipse/Eclipse-4.4/GWTT/.apt_generated/test/client/test2/MyWidgetClientModule$$ProvideSomeServiceFactory.java'
         [ERROR] Line 7: No source code is available for type dagger.Factory<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
```

I have the following libs on my Java build path:

[image]

Edit Gradle: I also tried to activate annotation processing with gradle in eclipse. Here is my gradle build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'apt'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'gwt'
apply plugin: 'jetty'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

eclipse {
    classpath {
       downloadSources=true
       downloadJavadoc=true
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.6'      
        classpath 'com.jimdo.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.5-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name = "sonatype"
        url = "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT:jar-with-dependencies'

    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava-gwt:18.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'   
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

gwt {
    gwtVersion='2.7.0'
    logLevel = 'INFO'
    minHeapSize = "512M";
    maxHeapSize = "1024M";


    compiler {
        strict = true;
    }

    modules 'test.GWTT'     
}

tasks.withType(de.richsource.gradle.plugins.gwt.AbstractGwtActionTask) {
    args '-XjsInteropMode', 'JS'
}
```

After `gradle build``I get:

```
/Users/mg/Documents/Grails/GGTS3.6.2/TestGradle2/src/main/java/test/client/GWTT.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
         MyWidgetGinjector injector = Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector.create();
                                      ^
  symbol:   variable Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector
```

I can see that `Dagger_MyWidgetGinjector.java`has been created in `build/source/apt/test/client/test2/`. I still need to figure out how I can add the newly generated source such that eclipse will find it using refresh dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger 2 doesn't shade its dependencies (yet) so you have to add all dagger-compiler dependencies to the factory path.

**EDIT:** there's a `jar-with-dependencies` flavor containing all dependencies to make it easier for users like you who don't use so-called *managed dependencies*, at the expense of possibly having conflicts when using other annotation processors with the same transitive dependencies. Ideally dagger-compiler should *shade* its dependencies to produce a conflict-free uber-jar; that'll come eventually I believe.

Comment: I added a lot of dependencies from the dagger2 compiler pom.xml but still I have the same error.

Comment: Is it better to use maven to get it running?

Comment: Actually, there's a `jar-with-dependencies` flavor of dagger-compiler that you can use (and you shouldn't need any other JAR in the factory path then). If you keep seeing an error, have a look at the "error view" in Eclipse to (try to) get more details about the error(s).

Comment: To your secondary question: I strongly recommend a tool (any tool: Maven, Ivy, Gradle, Buildr, etc.) to manage your dependencies. I couldn't live without such tools nowadays. YMMV.

Comment: Oh, and there's a conflict between the latest snapshots of Dagger 2 and auto-common <https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/114> so you should really use the jar-with-dependencies flavor if you can (i.e. until you need to add another annotation processor that share dependencies with Dagger 2)

Comment: What do you mean by ``jar-with-dependencies flavor`` How do I use a flavor and where?

Comment: The jar-with-dependencies JAR at https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/dagger/dagger-compiler/2.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thank you but now there are some conflicts when I do a GWT compile. See the edit of my post. javax.inject and dagger are missing .apt_generated folder but I have these jars on my build path. I think you are close to the solution. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Ah, you need the javax.inject sources JAR, and a small GWT module like with Dagger (javax/inject/Inject.gwt.xml)

Comment: With plain eclipse it works great but I still struggling with gradle. Please have a look at my edit. This might be very easy for you. Thanks Thomas.